# Open MP if OpenMP:...else

Tags: fortran, openmp, fortran90

Problem: 
I have a some code that myself and a few others have been writing, I took the code and made it use mpi and openmp with great results (helps that I am running it on a Blue Gene/Q).

One thing I am not a fan of is that now I cannot compile the code without the -openmp directive because to get the speedup I needed I used reduction variables.
Example:

```
!$OMP parallel do schedule(DYNAMIC, 4) reduction(min:min_val)
....
    min_val = some_expression(i)
....
!$OMP end parallel do
result = sqrt(min_val)
```

I am looking for something like:

```
!$OMP if OMP:
!$OMP min_val = some_expression(i)
!$OMP else:
if ( min_val .gt. some_expression(i) ) min_val = some_expression(i)
!$OMP end else
```

Anybody know of something like this?  Notice that without -openmp the !$OMP lines are ignored and the code runs normally with the correct, er same, answer.

Thanks,

(Yes it is FORTRAN code, but its almost identical to C and C++)

Comment: Still I wouldn't use C and C++ tags, you will get people using that anyway from the openmp tag.

Comment: The thing about the tags is, there’s a trivial solution in C and C++ using the normal preprocessor and `_Pragma`. I’m not sure if a similar solution exists for Fortran.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It is quite common practice to use pre-processed FORTRAN source files (usually their extension begins with a capital 'F' instead of a small one). Therefore the solution may be as trivial as in C.

Comment: @Massimiliano I’m not doubting that, I’m just saying that unless Fortran had a conceptually very similar preprocessor to C, a solution is unlikely to be transferrable, and that the [tag:c] and [tag:c++] tags were thus not useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to use pre-processed FORTRAN source file, you can always rely on the macro `_OPENMP` to be defined when using OpenMP. The simplest example is:

```
program pippo

#ifdef _OPENMP
print *, "OpenMP program"
#else
print *, "Non-OpenMP program"
#endif

end program pippo
```

Compiled with:

```
gfortran -fopenmp main.F90
```

the program will give the following output:

```
OpenMP program
```

If you are unwilling to use pre-processed source files, then you can set a variable using FORTRAN conditional compilation sentinel:

```
program pippo

  implicit none

  logical :: use_openmp = .false.

  !$ use_openmp = .true.
  !$ print *, "OpenMP program"
  if( .not. use_openmp) then
     print *, "Non-OpenMP program"
  end if

end program pippo
```

Answer (score 6):

To your exact question:

```
!$ whatever_statement
```

will use that statement only when compiled with OpenMP.

---

Otherwise, in your specific case, can't you just use:

```
!$OMP parallel do schedule(DYNAMIC, 4) reduction(min:min_val)
....
    min_val = min(min_val, some_expression(i))
....
!$OMP end parallel do

result = sqrt(min_val)
```

?

I'm using this normally with and without `-openmp` quite often.

Comment: Ah, this answers part of my question about running code only if an openmp compiled program.  Still curious about in a more general case, not having the "default" behavior run.  (Yes, your answer does answer this specific case marvelously though)